# Object created inside function not found by ggplot

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a csv of time series data for a number of sites that I produce ggplots for, showing changes in means using the changepoint package. I have written a function that takes the csv, performs some calculations to get the means then loops through the sites producing a plot for each. My problem is that an object created in the for loop isn't found.

A very simplified example is below but produces the same error:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-10"),
                         by = "day"),
              site1 = runif(10),
              site2 = runif(10),
              site3 = runif(10))

example <- function(df1){

    sname <- names(df1)[-1]

    for (i in 1:length(sname)){
            df2 <- df1[,c(1, 1+i)]
            df2$label <- factor(rep("ts", by=length(df2[,1])))

            plot <- ggplot()+
                    geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=date, y=df2[,2]))+
                    geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=date, y=df2[,2]))
            sname.i<-sname[i]
            filename<-paste0(sname.i, "-test-plot.pdf")
            ggsave(file=filename, plot)
    }
}

example(df1)
```

The error I get is: " Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'df2' not found"

I'm not quite sure what the problem is as I have created similar loops which have worked in the past. If I assign a value to i and step through the code within the loop it works fine. I'm thinking an environment problem? Or is ggsave doing something wiggy? Any help/pointers gratefully received.
Thanks.

Comment: When I run your code, the problem is `sname`. Without this variable being defined, `i` also remains undefined, and the same then happens to `df2`.

Comment: @vaettchen. Did you run the whole function or just the loop? I re-ran the example function on my home computer and still get the error as stated above. It fails for me on df2.

Comment: edited the question title to specify the problem correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You problem is not so much your code, but the implementation of the ggplot2 package. This package uses nonstandard evaluation, and that can seriously mess up your results.

Take a look at the example code at the end of this post. I create in the global environment a data frame called `df2` with different values. If I run your code now, you get plots that looks like this:

[image]

Note that on the X axis, it uses the correct dates, but the values on the Y axis are the ones from the dataframe `df2` that is in the global environment!  So the function `aes()` looks for the data in two different places. If you specify the name of a variable as a symbol (`date`) the function first looks in the data frame that is specified in the function call. However, an expression like `df2[,2]` cannot be found in the dataframe, as there is no variable with that name. Due to the way the `ggplot2` package is constructed, R will look for that in the global environment instead of the calling environment.

As per **wici**'s comment: Your best option is probably to use the function `aes_string()`, as this allows you to pass the aes in character form, and this function evaluates expressions in the correct environment :

```
plot <- ggplot()+
      geom_point(data=df2, aes_string(x="date", y=sname[i]))+
      geom_line(data=df2, aes_string(x="date", y=sname[i]))
```

Alternatively, you can get around that by using `eval()` and `parse()` like this:

```
example <- function(df1){

  sname <- names(df1)[-1]

  for (i in 1:length(sname)){
    df2 <- df1[,c(1, 1+i)]
    df2$label <- factor(rep("ts", by=length(df2[,1])))

    aesy <- sname[i]
    command <- paste("plot <- ggplot()+
      geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=date, y=",aesy,"))+
      geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=date, y=",aesy,"))")

    eval(parse(text=command))                     
    sname.i<-sname[i]
    print(plot)
  }
```

If you try that out with the example script below, you'll see that this time around you get the correct values displayed. Note that this is a suboptimal solution, as most solutions involving `eval()`. I'd go for `aes_string()` here.

---

EXAMPLE SCRIPT

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-10"),
                             by = "day"),
                  site1 = runif(10),
                  site2 = runif(10),
                  site3 = runif(10))

df2 <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2014-10-01"), as.Date("2014-10-10"),
                             by = "day"),
                  site1 = runif(10,10,20),
                  site2 = runif(10,10,20),
                  site3 = runif(10,10,20))

example <- function(df1){

  sname <- names(df1)[-1]

  for (i in 1:length(sname)){
    df2 <- df1[,c(1, 1+i)]
    df2$label <- factor(rep("ts", by=length(df2[,1])))

    plot <- ggplot()+
      geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=date, y=df2[,2]))+
      geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=date, y=df2[,2]))

    sname.i<-sname[i]
    print(plot)
  }
}

example(df1)
```

Comment: You are of course right, but ggplot2 also provides a function for regular evaluation of aesthetics. Just use `aes_string(x="date", y=aesy)` as your aesthetic generator.

Comment: @Joris. Thanks for that. In my efforts to convert what I used in base graphics to ggplot I can see where I've been going wrong.

Comment: @wici Thanks for pointing that out! I wasn't aware of that function `aes_string`. I've added it to the answer. If you want to post it as your own answer, let me know and I remove it again. You deserve to get the full credit for this.